# How to send push notifications to many users without triggering rate limit in google side?

Tags: php, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `php` and `use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;` to send push notifications to both `ios` and `android` and works great.

I want to do push notifications campaigns now.
Example:

Send push notification to all the users that meet a particular criteria, example: have purchased something.

**My question is:**

Is there any risk of doing this with a naive for loop ?

```
<?php
for ($customers as $customer) {
    $messaging = (new Factory())->createMessaging();
    // other stuff adding the subscription etc
    $message = CloudMessage::withTarget('token', $customer['subscription']['token'])
        ->withNotification(Notification::create(
            null,
            $data['message']
        ))
        ->withData($data)
        ->withAndroidConfig($this->prepareAndroidConfig($data))
        ->withApnsConfig($this->prepareApnsConfig($data));
    $messaging->send($message);
}
```

I am concerned if this will trigger rate limiting or if it is a proper way to do the campaigns.

I know that firebase cloud messaging offer campaings as well but they are not flexible for my use case. Have 2 drawbacks

1. I cannot add custom data to the notification
2. we don't have all user data in firebase to create proper filters for the audience ($customers variable in the simple example above)

Please suggest me how to implement this in the best way

Comment: In that particular case you should not send it with that script, but put it in a queue. Then run a worker reading this queue and send the messages from there and then remove it from the queue. With that concept you also can avoid rate limits for example by sending only 100 per minute.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but how would the queue help ? I can use a timer by modifying the for loop as well right and ensure that in a minute for example I make up to X num of calls

Comment: The queue makes it crash safe. What happens with your script if it crashes? Will you send the same message again?

Comment: @MarkusZeller no but I can store in redis/db the last successful item as well and retry from there. As long as the query has a reliable `sort by` this works beautifully (done multiple times in other places)

Comment: But anyway your conclusion is that it is totally fine to make multiple api calls to the firebase cloud messaging api endpoints and send the notifications one after the other while taking care not to reach the second-minute rate limit. Do they have any batch send functionality or something else ? I can code anything just gathering info here on what is the preferred and proper way to use FCM

Comment: If you use redis with a state, then it is kinda queue :) Your example looks like you want to fire all at once, which I don't believe will work, because there is certainly a quota which should be documented in the API reference.

Comment: `For Android, you can send up to 240 messages/minute and 5,000 messages/hour to a single device.` https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: seems like I don't even need to worry then. I just want to send 1 message to a single device every 24 hours to remind them for something. every 24h i will send around 500k messages to unique devices (reminder campaigns to all users that fullfill some criteria). The cronjob will run every day and send the messages I believe will be fine even with the for loop + try catch + store last successful id

Comment: I confirm that. You still can refactor when needed.